# xpath query to select nodes with and condition

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<AppXmlLogWritter>  
  <LogData>  
    <LogID>235820130202134128634953894887814709273</LogID>  
    <LogDateTime>20130202134128</LogDateTime>  
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>  
    <LogFlag>PACSFlag</LogFlag>  
    <LogApplication>PACSLogApplication</LogApplication>  
    <LogModule>PACSLogModule</LogModule>  
    <LogLocation>PACSLogLocation</LogLocation>  
    <LogText>PACSLogText</LogText>  
  </LogData>  
  <LogData>  
    <LogID>2358201302021341286349538948878147093861</LogID>  
    <LogDateTime>20130202134128</LogDateTime>  
    <LogType>Error</LogType>  
    <LogFlag>PACSFlag</LogFlag>  
    <LogApplication>PACSLogApplication</LogApplication>  
    <LogModule>PACSLogModule</LogModule>  
    <LogLocation>PACSLogLocation</LogLocation>  
    <LogText>PACSLogText</LogText>  
  </LogData>      
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

Get Nodes having LogApplication starts with 'P' and positon <=1 and >=2

> /AppXmlLogWritter/ LogData[LogApplication/text()[starts-with(. , 'P')]]and LogData[position()<=1 and position()>=2]

i have written above query but fails

Comment: Well not working how? Do you get an exception? Does it run but not return anything? What are you trying to achieve with the position clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[starts-with(LogApplication, 'P') and (position()<=1 and position()>=2)]`

Comment: @Means `positon <=1 and >=2` is mutually exclusive condition.

Comment: @Means `<=101 and >=200` is also mutually exclusive. There is no number in universe that could be less, then 101 (e.g. 100), but greater then 200 (e.g. 201). Maybe `>= 101 and <= 200` is implied? Or `OR` condition: `<= 101 or >= 200`?